# Cyrillic Google Font 'Montserrat' does not load

Tags: cyrillic, google-webfonts

I am trying to load the google font Montserrat. 
This works well for latin script, but seems to fall back whenever I use cyrillic type.

What am I missing?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates:700|Montserrat:400,400i,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Headline </h1>
  <p>Lorem <i>ipsum</i> dolor sit amet <b>consectetur</b>, adipisicing elit. Saepe, qui.
    <p>

      <h1> Хеадлине </h1>
      <p>Лорем <i>ипсум</i> долор сит амет <b>цонсецтетур</b>, адиписицинг елит. Саепе, яуи.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser was loading a local version of this font that did not contain the cyrillic subset.